# Python - sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Я открыл права на всё, но все равно не работает. Ubuntu 18.04.

Код:

```
conn=connect('home/usr/downloads/databases/database_for_enter.db3')
cursor = conn.cursor()

conn.commit()


cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Enter(login REAL, password TEXT)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Enter VALUES(?, ?)", (login_enter.get(), password_enter.get()))

conn.close()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: вы можете открыть данный файл в Python: `open('home/usr/downloads/databases/database_for_enter.db3')`?

Comment: Большое спасибо